# jsPDF within Cordova / Phonegap - Impossible to add images

Tags: android, cordova, pdf-generation, phonegap-build, jspdf

I have a problem,

I'm trying to add images in my pdf with jsPDF. *b64Tab* is an array containing the base64 data of my jpg images that i want to add.

After the

```
doc.output();
```

The different pages are created with the text added, but the images are not displayed. I test this on a 4.2.2 Android phone.

Here is a piece of code :

```
for (var j = 0; j < b64Tab.length; j++) {
    doc.addPage();
    doc.setFontSize(22);
    doc.text(130, 65, descriptions[j]);
    doc.addImage(b64Tab[j], 'JPEG', 40, 100, 500, 500);
}
```

I'm using the latest jsPDF's build.

Any help would be welcomed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using File plugin then replace pdf output with `doc.output("blob");`

If you are using File plugin then create a buffer to write on the file eg.

```
var data = getPDFFile();
var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(data.length);
var array = new Uint8Array(buffer);
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    array[i] = data.charCodeAt(i);
}
writer.write(buffer); // here you write on file using File plugin
```